# IM+ Disable status string

Tags: instant-messaging

How to disable status string "On Android with IM+" when using IM+ for skype? I do not want to show that I am away from PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this site](http://bestappsforandroid.blogspot.fi/2011/08/android-messenger-for-facebook-msn.html), it's possible to change the status by tapping it and selecting another status message. It's possible that this is not available in the free version, since they usually contain ads.